# Adding Multiple Accounts To Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

Hi I have MetaMask installed and Im working with the Remix IDE. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to work out how to add multiple accounts to here:

[image]

so that I can test transactions using a different ether account. At the minute I have to go into MetaMax change the account and then refresh the Remix window to show the new account. If I click on the drop down only 1 account shows.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a testnet to test your code or any environment?

Comment: This is a limitation of using `Injected Web3` as your Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `Environment` input and select `JavaScriptVM`.

You will see the list of 5 accounts with a balance of 100 Ether each.
[image]

Comment: You can also connect to a locally running node (like ganache) by choosing `Web3 Provider` as your `Environment` and entering the correct url (ie http://localhost:8545) while the node is running. If using ganache, this will give you access to all 10 accounts made available by ganache.